# jQuery Multiple Backgrounds script not working in IE

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm using http://www.chicowebdesign.com/blog/2010/10/21/updated-jquery-multiple-background-plug-in/

As they state to, but in IE the multiple backgrounds do not work, any ideas, suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/6JtNr/ (just the css im using)

I'm including jQuery, including their script after jquery is loaded..

Ideas?

Comment: What jquery version are you using? There is an known isssue with this plugin: jQuery 1.4.3 will cause layout errors in Internet Explorer 6 and 7. Default to 1.4.2 instead. Please check again all the known issues.

Comment: Tried using 1.4.1, 1.4.2, same issue, tried using latest version, same issue no matter what version of jQuery I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, reading the instructions on the page, you need to change your css to:

`.container {
    /* For unsupported browsers /
    background: url('../images/backgrounds/fifteen.jpg') no-repeat 13440px 0;
    / For CSS3 Supported Browsers */
    background: url('../images/backgrounds/one.jpg') no-repeat top 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/two.jpg') no-repeat 960px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/three.jpg') no-repeat 1920px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/four.jpg') no-repeat 2880px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/five.jpg') no-repeat 3840px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/six.jpg') no-repeat 4800px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/seven.jpg') no-repeat 5760px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/eight.jpg') no-repeat 6720px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/nine.jpg') no-repeat 7680px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/ten.jpg') no-repeat 8640px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/eleven.jpg') no-repeat 9600px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/twelve.jpg') no-repeat 10560px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/thirteen.jpg') no-repeat 11520px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/fourteen.jpg') no-repeat 12480px 0,
    url('../images/backgrounds/fifteen.jpg') no-repeat 13440px 0;
    width: 14400px;
    height: 1020px;
}`

Note that I moved the width and height to the bottom, some people said in the comments of that library that the background needs to be first in the style tag.  Also, as per the instructions, you need to have a separate background line calling the last background image for unsupported browsers.